# Check if input is not empty, if it is, make others inputs required

Tags: jquery

I have two inputs :

```
      <label>Nom de famille du père à la naissance</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="11"><br>
      <label>Prénom usuel du père</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="12"><br>
```

What I want to do is that if one of the two inputs is not empty, i wanna make them both required. And i want it to be in real time.

Here is my jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//NOM PERE
if($('[name="11"]').val() != ""){
    $('[name="11"]').prop('required', true);
    $('[name="12"]').prop('required', true);
}
});
```

I have no idea why... it's not working... Please some help

EDIT : I found my problem... I had to do the validation just after i click on submit button :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//NOM PERE
$('#submit').click(function(e){
if($('[name="11"]').val() !== ""){
    $('[name="11"]').prop('required', true);
    $('[name="12"]').prop('required', true);
}
});
});
```

Thanks you btw...

Comment: Then you need to check for input name 12 also

Comment: If you found an answer, please response to your own question below, not on your question.

Answer (score 0):

use `!==` instead of `!=`  and its better to use `$(this)`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//NOM PERE
if($('[name="11"]').val() !== ""){
    $(this).prop('required', true);
    $('[name="12"]').prop('required', true);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `is(':empty')`

i.e.:

```
  if ($('[name="11"]').is(':empty'))
```

---

for more info see http://api.jquery.com/is/ and http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/